# My First Div Moves When I Change Margin Of My Second Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

`Basiccaly When I Change The Margins of my div called contact my second div (name lesson) changes its position pls help`

Pls Help Me , My Div Changes position after chaning margin of second div
if somone can help me pls help

here is my html :

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
           <div id="popo">
                      
                  </div>
          <div id="calcuDiv">
              <button id="calcuBtn" onclick="calcu()">Calculators
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  Calculate AnyThing With The Calculators We Provide You With
              </button>
          </div>
          <div id="AboutDiv">
              <button id="AboutBtn" onclick="faq()">FAQ
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  Look At Some Frequently Asked Questions
              </button>
          </div>
          
          <div id="GameDiv">
              <button id="gameBtn" onclick="game()">Games
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  Play Games Related To Maths On Your Selected Lessons
              </button>
          </div>
          
            
                  
                  <div id="contactDiv">
                      <button id="contactBtn" onclick="contact()">Features
                          <br>
                          <br>
                         Know About The Many Features Of Our Website
                      </button>
                      </div>
          
                      <div id="lessonDiv">
                          <button id="lessonBtn" onclick="lesson()">Lessons
                              <br>
                              <br>
                             Look At Various Lessons According To Your Choices
                          </button>
                          </div>
          </div>
          
          
          <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer"  id="hieo" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;hi</span>
          
          <script>
          function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
          }
          
          function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
          }
          </script>
```

here is my css:

```
#calcuDiv
{
width: 60%;
height: 40%;
transition: 0.4;
border: none;
}

#calcuBtn
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        background-image: url(
'colorfulcalcu-modified.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-bottom: 100;
        border: none;
        margin-top: 0;
        transition: 0.4;
}

#calcuBtn:hover
{
    transition: 0.4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        background-image: url(
'colorfulcalcu.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        border: none;   
        font-size: 25px;
}

#AboutDiv
{
width: 40%;
height: 40%;
border: none;
transition: 0.4;
margin-left: 60%;
margin-top: -286px;
}

#AboutBtn
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
background-image: url('ok.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        border: none;
        transition: 0.4;
        font-size: 22px;
}

#AboutBtn:hover
{
    transition: 0.4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        background-image: url(
'ok1.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        border: none;
        font-size: 25px;
}

#GameDiv
{

border: none;
transition: 0.4;
margin-top: 200;
}

#gameBtn
{
    width: 34%;
    height: 47.5%;
        background-image: url(
'game-modified.jpeg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
font-size: 22px;
        border: none;
        margin-bottom: 100%;
        margin-top: -200;
        transition: 0.4;
}

#gameBtn:hover
{
    transition: 0.4;
        background-image: url(
'game.jpeg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 2rem;
        border: none;
        font-size: 25px;
}

#popo
{
        height: 90px;
        background-color: black;
}

#contactDiv
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 463px;
border: none;
transition: 0.4;
margin-bottom: 400;
margin-left: 285px;
}

#contactBtn
{
        height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
        background-image: url(
'quiz-modified.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 2rem;
     margin-left: 50%;
        transition: 0.4;
        margin-top: 1130px;
        border: none;
}

#contactBtn:hover
{
    transition: 0.4;
        background-image: url(
'quiz.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 2rem;
        border: none;
        font-size: 25px;
}


#menu
{
 height: 100%;
 width: 10%;
 float: right;
 background-color: black;
 border: none;
 color: white;
}

#lessonDiv
{
transition: 0.4;
height: 339px;
width: 450px;
background-color: white;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: 70.5%;
margin-top: -1462;

}

#myNav
{
        max-width:100%;
}

#lessonBtn
{

        height: 110%;
    width: 100%;
        background-image: url(
'lessons-modified.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 2rem;
        transition: 0.4;
        border: none;
}

#lessonBtn:hover
{
    transition: 0.4;
        background-image: url(
'lessons.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        color: aliceblue;
        font-size: 2rem;
        border: none;
        font-size: 25px;
}


.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
```

Here Is aal the code if you are able to help me pls do help,
it is big coding but i really need help its my competion so i realy need help i dont have much time to complete so it will be a great help to me .  pls help me and thank u so much for reading this

i was trying to change the postition of contact div but my lesson div changes its position when i change margin of my contact div

Comment: Could you please make a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so that we can better help you ? Because your css is pretty big, we don't have the images and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox) in this case.

So, basically you should wrap the `contactDiv` and `lessonDiv` in a new container (e.g. `flex-container`).

Here is a code snippet:

```html
<body>
  <style>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      gap: 20px;
    }
    
    .contactDiv,
    .lessonDiv {
      border: 3px solid black;
      width: 400px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .contactDiv {
      background-color: crimson;
    }
    
    .lessonDiv {
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="contactDiv">
      <p>This a contactDiv</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lessonDiv">
      <p>This a lessonDiv</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```